# Google Chart my Y axis dont show right numbers?

Tags: charts, google-analytics, google-visualization

```
chs=800x300
&chxl=1:|10:00|11:00|19:30|2:|Tidspunkt|3:|Kcal|
&chxt=y,x,x,y
&cht=lc
&chco=3072F3
&chds=3735.6
&chd=t:1198,2663,3396
&chxr=0,599,3429.96
&chdl=Energi
&chdlp=b
&chls=1|1|1
&chma=5,5,5,25
&chm=o,000000,0,-1,5|o,000000,1,-1,5|o,000000,2,-1,5
```

Is what i have.. test it here:
http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_playground.html

```
10:00 should be 1198
11:00 should be 2663
19::30 should be 3396
```

Which it is, but in the chart it is not displaying right. Look at the 10:00 dot its above 2500, but the value is only 1198?

What should be fixed here?

This has a bounty of 250 and is relatively easy for those who know about Google charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the following values to this and it seems to work:

```
&chds=599,3429.96
```

You had a problem where the axis was scaled differently than your data.  The chxr should have the same range as chds.